# Txt Python looping

Tags: python

I'm starting in Python. I have several tasks cleaning a txt data, but I'm starting with the basic one, which is replacing every single comma with a space. I know that I can select the entire line and apply replace value, but I need to do it by character. Anyway, it didn't work.

```py
with  open(r'C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\addresses.txt', 'r') as data:
    with  open(r'C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\addresses_final.txt', 'w') as final:

        for line in data:
            prev = ''
            for char in line:
                if char == ',':
                    char == ' '
                row = prev + char
                prev = row
            final.write(row)
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fast answer: your code is functional if you simply change that line:

```
char == ' '
```

which is a boolean expression, to an assignment, to this line:

```
char = ' '
```